# External page refresh doesn't work using knockout javascript and html

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am working on an aps.net mvc application in which I am trying to refresh an external webpage on a button click using knockout javascript using the following script

Knockout Js

```
self.refreshDomestic= function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://10.10.10.33:82/Home/DomesticDeals",
            success: function () {

                    location.reload();

            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(self.refreshDomestic, 10);
```

I am binding the above function to an html button as follows

```
<td >
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: function() {add();$root.refreshDomestic();} value="Add New Entry" />
</td>
```

but the above script doesn't refresh the page specified and I also made sure that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource.

**May I know where I made a mistake?**

Comment: (1) What is `data`? (2) Where is your `error` handler? Check the browwser console for errors as well...

Comment: well I was just trying by passing some data but that was an older version.I have edited the code

Comment: Same second question though. Where is your `error` handler? If you're not reloading, you're not successfully completing the ajax call. You'll need to create an error handler and use `console.log()` to output the results.

Comment: Refresh an external page? You mean load a external page? You're not showing the external page, you just want to "hit" the page when the button is clicked?

Comment: @SteenT I dont want to load the external page. all I wanted is refresh wherever it is open so that some data from database is updated on that external page

Comment: Use the dev tools from your favourite browser and check the AJAX call result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to manage location.reload in ajax.jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078247/how-to-manage-location-reload-in-ajax-jquery)   Use `document.location.reload()`

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? You aren't trying to refresh the domestic deals page?

Comment: yes I am trying to refresh domestic deals page but that is coming from an external website